# Undefined reference to `typeinfo for class' and undefined reference to `vtable for class'

Tags: c++, undefined-reference, vtable

I'm dealing with inheritance in C++. I wanted to write a program for addition and subtraction of two arrays. Heres my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class root
{
    protected :

            int size;
            double *array;

    public :

        virtual ~root() {}
        virtual root* add(const root&) = 0;
        virtual root* sub(const root&) = 0;
        virtual istream& in(istream&, root&) = 0;

        virtual int getSize() const = 0;
        virtual void setSize(int);
        virtual int getAt(int) const = 0;
};

class aa: public root
{

    public :

        aa();
        aa(int);
        aa(const aa&);
        root* add(const root& a);
        root* sub(const root& a);
        istream& in(istream&, root&){}
        int getSize() const;
        void setSize(int);
        int getAt(int) const;
};

class bb: public root
{
public:
    bb() { }
    bb(const bb& b) { }
    root* add(const root& a);
    root* sub(const root& a);
    istream& in(istream&, root&){}
    int getSize() const{}
    void setSize(int){}
    int getAt(int) const{}
};

aa::aa()
{
    size = 0;
    array = NULL;
}

aa::aa(int nsize)
{
    size = nsize;
    array = new double[size+1];
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        array[i] = 0;
}

root* aa::add(const root& a)
{
    for (int i=0; i<a.getSize(); i++)
        array[i] += a.getAt(i);
    return new aa();
}

root* aa::sub(const root& a)
{
}

int aa::getSize() const
{
    return size;
}

void aa::setSize(int nsize)
{
    size = nsize;
    array = new double[size+1];
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        array[i] = 0;
}

int aa::getAt(int index) const
{
    return array[index];
}

root* bb::add(const root& a)
{
    return new bb();
}

root* bb::sub(const root& a)
{

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
}
```

But I have a strange errors:

```
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.o||In function `root::~root()':|
Untitled2.cpp:(.text._ZN4rootD2Ev[_ZN4rootD5Ev]+0xb)||undefined reference to `vtable for root'|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.o||In function `root::root()':|
Untitled2.cpp:(.text._ZN4rootC2Ev[_ZN4rootC5Ev]+0x8)||undefined reference to `vtable for root'|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.o:(.rodata._ZTI2bb[typeinfo for bb]+0x8)||undefined reference to `typeinfo for root'|
/home/brian/Desktop/Temp/Untitled2.o:(.rodata._ZTI2aa[typeinfo for aa]+0x8)||undefined reference to `typeinfo for root'|
||=== Build finished: 4 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

dont know from where they came from, dont now how to 'fix' them. Thanks in advance;)

Comment: Don't use naked pointers. Just don't go there. This is horribly broken code. (Also, look up how constructor initializer lists work.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`root::setSize` isn't declared pure virtual, which means it must be defined. Presumably, it should be as pure as the other functions:

```
virtual void setSize(int) = 0;
                          ^^^
```

If you're interested in the gory details of why you get that particular error: this compiler needs to generate the class's virtual/RTTI metadata somewhere and, if the class declares a non-pure, non-inline virtual function, it will generate it in the same translation unit as that function's definition. Since there is no definition, they don't get generated, giving that error.

Comment: +1 for giving the gory details!

Answer (score 1):

Your `root::setSize` is not defined, and not declared an pure virtual function. Either add `= 0` to the end of the function (making it pure virtal), or define a `root::setSize` function.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because you haven't implemented

```
    virtual void setSize(int);
```

in `root` or declared it as pure virtual by adding `=0`